# PowerShell, pipeline compatible Select-String function

Tags: string, powershell, pipeline

This is more about my weak understanding of pipelines and functions than anything, so would appreciate help. As an example:

```
Get-Service | Select-String win   # fails
Get-Service | Out-String -Stream | Select-String win   # works
```

I've seen explanations on why the `Out-String -Stream` is required, but it frustrates me a bit, so I want a function `oss` that does the `Out-String -Stream` part. My idea is like this:

```
function oss { Out-String -Stream }
Get-Service | oss | Select-String win
```

But this fails. Can someone tell me how to make this work, i.e. make the `oss` function pipeline compatible?

And from that, how do we then do the following (obviously this doesn't work, but I'm really curious how this would be achieved)?

```
function slx { Out-String -Stream | Select-String <and allow all of the same switches as Select-String> }
Get-Service | slx win
```

So that, effectively, `slx` is a variant of `Select-String` that always does the `Out-String -Stream` part as well?

Comment: Should filtering not done like this: `get-service | where { $_.DisplayName -Match 'win' }`  (to find all services that contain 'win') ?

Comment: Have you tried get-Service -name "win*" ?  This gets around the need for a pipeline, but does not address the gist of your question.

Comment: Thanks. You are both right of course, but this is not really what I was wanting to achieve. As I was saying, this is just an example as I'm trying to understand how to better manipulate the pipeline to build functions that are pipeline aware. i.e. when faced with a situation like this, how would I go about building these two forms of pipeline aware functions, a) one that would just mimic something like `Out-String -Stream` and b) one that would extend the functionality of `Select-String` in this particular way.

Comment: @YorSubs - take a look at advanced functions. **_you need to define a parameter and tell it to accept pipeline input_**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I appreciate that you want to learn, so I will not just give you a working solution, but also explain a few things.

It seems like your you have a basic understanding of how functions and the pipeline work. If you want to learn more about it have a look at [about_Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-5.1) and [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-5.1) (and related help topics), or let me know what in particular you want to know in the comments.

One thing you need to understand though if you are new to Powershell, is that it it's object-based, not text-based. It's objects that are passed through the pipeline, and you should work with them as such, and not convert them to text (unless for file output).

The documentation about [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1) states specifically, that it is meant for *finding text* in strings and files. But this is not what you are trying to do here. As I said, work with objects, not text. So omit the `Out-String`. The proper command to filter objects in a pipeline is [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-5.1) or one of its aliases `where` or `?`.

Example:

```
Get-Service | where { $_.DisplayName -like *win* }
# in newer Powershell versions, this shorter syntax is also possible:
Get-Service | where DisplayName -like *win*
```

But as you specifically asked about making a function "pipeline aware", this can be done in several ways. But your problem is not only getting input from the pipeline, but also they way you pass it to `Out-String`, because the output will change if you pass only one item at a time.

Basically you have to pass the input all at once. So, the simplest way to achieve this in your case is using the [$Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#input) automatic variable:

```
 function oss { $Input | Out-String -Stream }
```

If you need to process one pipeline item at a time, there are more ways to get pipeline input. For example an [advanced function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-5.1):

```bsh
function example { 
    process {
        $_ # current item
    }
}
```

You can also use the [parameter attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1#valuefrompipeline-argument) to bind the pipeline input to a function parameter:

```bsh
function example {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $InputObject
    )
    process {
        $InputObject # current item
    }
}
```

The last way I can think of is using a [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-5.1#filters), which is a special kind of function which is specifically designed to perform an operation on each pipeline element:

```bsh
filter example {
    $_ # current item
}
```

To learn more about it I recommend a google search which will quickly provide you with useful articles such as [Build a PowerShell function for the pipeline](https://4sysops.com/archives/build-a-powershell-function-for-the-pipeline/) or [Incorporating Pipelined Input into PowerShell Functions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/incorporating-pipelined-input-into-powershell-functions/).

If you truly want to build a method that is basically a wrapper for another cmdlet like `Out-String` or `Select-String` with all the same switches, you should have a look at [proxy functions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/). But I think this would be overkill for what you're trying to do:

```bsh
function oss {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [psobject]$InputObject
    )
    begin
    {
        try {
            $outBuffer = $null
            if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
            {
                $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
            }
            # set -Stream switch always
            $PSBoundParameters["Stream"] = $true
            $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Out-String', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
            $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
            $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
            $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }
    process
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }
    end
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.End()
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely fascinating, really appreciate this @marsze. I've used PowerShell quite a long time, but this area has always been a big question mark for me on how to achieve these things. I've looked a few times at advanced_functions type pages, but always found them a bit inscrutable and confusing. These are great examples that I can really get stuck into (always find I learn better by having examples that I can connect to some practical task). I've got a bit of work to do to properly go through these..., really great thanks!

Comment: Nicely done; as an aside: the code that is auto-generated for proxy functions has some minor flaws; see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1086. I think it would make sense to remove the out-buffer part of the code here.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This answer ***complements* [marsze's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64631521/45375)**.

---

**Windows PowerShell v5.1 and PowerShell [Core] v6+ have an `oss` function *built in***, which effectively provides the functionality of `Out-String -Stream` via a proxy function, as shown in @marsze's answer.

- As an aside: the code that is auto-generated when you scaffold a proxy function has minor flaws as of PowerShell 7.1; in short: the `OutBuffer`-related code only applies to server-side proxy functions that need to guard against DoS (denial-of-service) attacks, and the `throw` statements should be `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)` instead - see [GitHub issue #10863](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10863#issuecomment-545621624).

While this helper function is useful, *it shouldn't be required in the first place*, because **[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) should implicitly operate on *formatted* output to begin with:**

- That is, for input that isn't already a string (text), `Select-String` should search the same richly formatted text representation that you see in the *console* (terminal).

  - Note: As pointed out in marsze's answer, in *programmatic* use, for robustness, you should take advantage of PowerShell's object-oriented nature and query *properties* instead, with `Where-Object`.
    However, **for quick-and-dirty *interactive* use it can be very convenient to search through the for-display representations**.
- [GitHub suggestion #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726#issuecomment-567628146) proposes just that, though there seem to be backward-compatibility concerns, even though I think there shouldn't be.

---

You can adapt the proxy-function approach from marsze's answers to properly implement the `slx` function you envision, as **advanced function `Select-StringFormatted`, aliased to `scs`** (see rationale below; of course, you can also define `slx`).

Note:

- The bulk of the code is the auto-generated declaration of the same parameters that `Select-String` supports; the actual proxying (wrapping) code via `Out-String -Stream` is minimal.
- Alias `scs` is what `Select-String`'s built-in alias `sls` *should have been*, given that the official alias prefix for [approved verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) `Select` is `sc`, not `ls`; in PowerShell [Core] v6+ you an easily verify that with `Get-Verb Select`.  Since the implicit `Out-String -Stream` behavior should be `Select-String`'s default behavior anyway, I think it makes sense to pick this alias; if/when `Select-String` gets fixed, you can redefine `scs` to point to `Select-String`.
- All parameters supported as of v7.0 are declared; if you try to use ones only introduced in 7.0 in earlier versions, namely `-Culture`, `-Raw`, and `-NoEmphasis`, they are ignored and a warning is emitted.
- Example command (compare to the output from `Get-Process | sls service`):

  ```
  PS> Get-Process | scs service  # scs == Select-StringFormatted

      395      16     3728      14656              5664   0 SecurityHealthService                                                                                
      360      11     3864       7696               632   0 services                                                                                             
      173      12     3324       8628              2388   0 VGAuthService
  ```

Note: The function below is also available as [an MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/46fea9e6e5ef1a3ceaf681c976cb68e3), and only the latter will be maintained going forward. Assuming you have looked at the linked code to ensure that it is safe (which I can personally assure you of, but you should always check), you can install it as follows:

```
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/46fea9e6e5ef1a3ceaf681c976cb68e3/raw/Select-StringFormatted.ps1 | iex
```

```
Set-Alias scs Select-StringFormatted

function Select-StringFormatted {
  <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Select-String wrapper command that for non-string input searches the
    *formatted* object representations rather than the often useless
    .ToString() representations.

    All Select-String parameters are supported. See the latter's help for more.

    .EXAMPLE
    Get-Process | Select-StringFormatted pwsh

    Output lines that contain "pwsh" in Get-Process' formatted output.

    .LINK
    Select-String

    #>
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'File', HelpUri = 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2097119')]
  param(
    [ValidateSet('Ordinal', 'Invariant', 'Current', '', 'af', 'af-NA', 'af-ZA', 'agq', 'agq-CM', 'ak', 'ak-GH', 'am', 'am-ET', 'ar', 'ar-001', 'ar-AE', 'ar-BH', 'ar-DJ', 'ar-DZ', 'ar-EG', 'ar-EH', 'ar-ER', 'ar-IL', 'ar-IQ', 'ar-JO', 'ar-KM', 'ar-KW', 'ar-LB', 'ar-LY', 'ar-MA', 'ar-MR', 'ar-OM', 'ar-PS', 'ar-QA', 'ar-SA', 'ar-SD', 'ar-SO', 'ar-SS', 'ar-SY', 'ar-TD', 'ar-TN', 'ar-YE', 'arn', 'arn-CL', 'as', 'as-IN', 'asa', 'asa-TZ', 'ast', 'ast-ES', 'az', 'az-Cyrl', 'az-Cyrl-AZ', 'az-Latn', 'az-Latn-AZ', 'ba', 'ba-RU', 'bas', 'bas-CM', 'be', 'be-BY', 'bem', 'bem-ZM', 'bez', 'bez-TZ', 'bg', 'bg-BG', 'bm', 'bm-ML', 'bn', 'bn-BD', 'bn-IN', 'bo', 'bo-CN', 'bo-IN', 'br', 'br-FR', 'brx', 'brx-IN', 'bs', 'bs-Cyrl', 'bs-Cyrl-BA', 'bs-Latn', 'bs-Latn-BA', 'byn', 'byn-ER', 'ca', 'ca-AD', 'ca-ES', 'ca-FR', 'ca-IT', 'ccp', 'ccp-BD', 'ccp-IN', 'ce', 'ce-RU', 'ceb', 'ceb-PH', 'cgg', 'cgg-UG', 'chr', 'chr-US', 'ckb', 'ckb-IQ', 'ckb-IR', 'co', 'co-FR', 'cs', 'cs-CZ', 'cv', 'cv-RU', 'cy', 'cy-GB', 'da', 'da-DK', 'da-GL', 'dav', 'dav-KE', 'de', 'de-AT', 'de-BE', 'de-CH', 'de-DE', 'de-IT', 'de-LI', 'de-LU', 'dje', 'dje-NE', 'dsb', 'dsb-DE', 'dua', 'dua-CM', 'dv', 'dv-MV', 'dyo', 'dyo-SN', 'dz', 'dz-BT', 'ebu', 'ebu-KE', 'ee', 'ee-GH', 'ee-TG', 'el', 'el-CY', 'el-GR', 'en', 'en-001', 'en-150', 'en-AD', 'en-AE', 'en-AG', 'en-AI', 'en-AL', 'en-AR', 'en-AS', 'en-AT', 'en-AU', 'en-BA', 'en-BB', 'en-BD', 'en-BE', 'en-BG', 'en-BI', 'en-BM', 'en-BR', 'en-BS', 'en-BW', 'en-BZ', 'en-CA', 'en-CC', 'en-CH', 'en-CK', 'en-CL', 'en-CM', 'en-CN', 'en-CO', 'en-CX', 'en-CY', 'en-CZ', 'en-DE', 'en-DG', 'en-DK', 'en-DM', 'en-EE', 'en-ER', 'en-ES', 'en-FI', 'en-FJ', 'en-FK', 'en-FM', 'en-FR', 'en-GB', 'en-GD', 'en-GG', 'en-GH', 'en-GI', 'en-GM', 'en-GR', 'en-GU', 'en-GY', 'en-HK', 'en-HR', 'en-HU', 'en-ID', 'en-IE', 'en-IL', 'en-IM', 'en-IN', 'en-IO', 'en-IS', 'en-IT', 'en-JE', 'en-JM', 'en-JP', 'en-KE', 'en-KI', 'en-KN', 'en-KR', 'en-KY', 'en-LC', 'en-LR', 'en-LS', 'en-LT', 'en-LU', 'en-LV', 'en-ME', 'en-MG', 'en-MH', 'en-MM', 'en-MO', 'en-MP', 'en-MS', 'en-MT', 'en-MU', 'en-MV', 'en-MW', 'en-MX', 'en-MY', 'en-NA', 'en-NF', 'en-NG', 'en-NL', 'en-NO', 'en-NR', 'en-NU', 'en-NZ', 'en-PG', 'en-PH', 'en-PK', 'en-PL', 'en-PN', 'en-PR', 'en-PT', 'en-PW', 'en-RO', 'en-RS', 'en-RU', 'en-RW', 'en-SA', 'en-SB', 'en-SC', 'en-SD', 'en-SE', 'en-SG', 'en-SH', 'en-SI', 'en-SK', 'en-SL', 'en-SS', 'en-SX', 'en-SZ', 'en-TC', 'en-TH', 'en-TK', 'en-TO', 'en-TR', 'en-TT', 'en-TV', 'en-TW', 'en-TZ', 'en-UA', 'en-UG', 'en-UM', 'en-US', 'en-US-POSIX', 'en-VC', 'en-VG', 'en-VI', 'en-VU', 'en-WS', 'en-ZA', 'en-ZM', 'en-ZW', 'eo', 'eo-001', 'es', 'es-419', 'es-AG', 'es-AI', 'es-AR', 'es-AW', 'es-BB', 'es-BL', 'es-BM', 'es-BO', 'es-BQ', 'es-BR', 'es-BS', 'es-BZ', 'es-CA', 'es-CL', 'es-CO', 'es-CR', 'es-CU', 'es-CW', 'es-DM', 'es-DO', 'es-EA', 'es-EC', 'es-ES', 'es-FK', 'es-GD', 'es-GF', 'es-GL', 'es-GP', 'es-GQ', 'es-GT', 'es-GY', 'es-HN', 'es-HT', 'es-IC', 'es-KN', 'es-KY', 'es-LC', 'es-MF', 'es-MQ', 'es-MS', 'es-MX', 'es-NI', 'es-PA', 'es-PE', 'es-PH', 'es-PM', 'es-PR', 'es-PY', 'es-SR', 'es-SV', 'es-SX', 'es-TC', 'es-TT', 'es-US', 'es-UY', 'es-VC', 'es-VE', 'es-VG', 'es-VI', 'et', 'et-EE', 'eu', 'eu-ES', 'ewo', 'ewo-CM', 'fa', 'fa-AF', 'fa-IR', 'ff', 'ff-Latn', 'ff-Latn-BF', 'ff-Latn-CM', 'ff-Latn-GH', 'ff-Latn-GM', 'ff-Latn-GN', 'ff-Latn-GW', 'ff-Latn-LR', 'ff-Latn-MR', 'ff-Latn-NE', 'ff-Latn-NG', 'ff-Latn-SL', 'ff-Latn-SN', 'fi', 'fi-FI', 'fil', 'fil-PH', 'fo', 'fo-DK', 'fo-FO', 'fr', 'fr-BE', 'fr-BF', 'fr-BI', 'fr-BJ', 'fr-BL', 'fr-CA', 'fr-CD', 'fr-CF', 'fr-CG', 'fr-CH', 'fr-CI', 'fr-CM', 'fr-DJ', 'fr-DZ', 'fr-FR', 'fr-GA', 'fr-GF', 'fr-GN', 'fr-GP', 'fr-GQ', 'fr-HT', 'fr-KM', 'fr-LU', 'fr-MA', 'fr-MC', 'fr-MF', 'fr-MG', 'fr-ML', 'fr-MQ', 'fr-MR', 'fr-MU', 'fr-NC', 'fr-NE', 'fr-PF', 'fr-PM', 'fr-RE', 'fr-RW', 'fr-SC', 'fr-SN', 'fr-SY', 'fr-TD', 'fr-TG', 'fr-TN', 'fr-VU', 'fr-WF', 'fr-YT', 'fur', 'fur-IT', 'fy', 'fy-NL', 'ga', 'ga-IE', 'gaa', 'gaa-GH', 'gd', 'gd-GB', 'gez', 'gez-ER', 'gez-ET', 'gl', 'gl-ES', 'gn', 'gn-PY', 'gsw', 'gsw-CH', 'gsw-FR', 'gsw-LI', 'gu', 'gu-IN', 'guz', 'guz-KE', 'gv', 'gv-IM', 'ha', 'ha-GH', 'ha-NE', 'ha-NG', 'haw', 'haw-US', 'he', 'he-IL', 'hi', 'hi-IN', 'hi-Latn', 'hr', 'hr-BA', 'hr-HR', 'hsb', 'hsb-DE', 'hu', 'hu-HU', 'hy', 'hy-AM', 'ia', 'ia-001', 'id', 'id-ID', 'ig', 'ig-NG', 'ii', 'ii-CN', 'io', 'io-001', 'is', 'is-IS', 'it', 'it-CH', 'it-IT', 'it-SM', 'it-VA', 'iu', 'iu-CA', 'ja', 'ja-JP', 'jbo', 'jbo-001', 'jgo', 'jgo-CM', 'jmc', 'jmc-TZ', 'jv', 'jv-ID', 'ka', 'ka-GE', 'kab', 'kab-DZ', 'kaj', 'kaj-NG', 'kam', 'kam-KE', 'kcg', 'kcg-NG', 'kde', 'kde-TZ', 'kea', 'kea-CV', 'khq', 'khq-ML', 'ki', 'ki-KE', 'kk', 'kk-KZ', 'kkj', 'kkj-CM', 'kl', 'kl-GL', 'kln', 'kln-KE', 'km', 'km-KH', 'kn', 'kn-IN', 'ko', 'ko-KP', 'ko-KR', 'kok', 'kok-IN', 'kpe', 'kpe-GN', 'kpe-LR', 'ks', 'ks-Arab', 'ks-Arab-IN', 'ks-Aran', 'ks-Aran-IN', 'ks-Deva', 'ks-IN', 'ksb', 'ksb-TZ', 'ksf', 'ksf-CM', 'ksh', 'ksh-DE', 'ku', 'ku-TR', 'kw', 'kw-GB', 'ky', 'ky-KG', 'lag', 'lag-TZ', 'lb', 'lb-LU', 'lg', 'lg-UG', 'lkt', 'lkt-US', 'ln', 'ln-AO', 'ln-CD', 'ln-CF', 'ln-CG', 'lo', 'lo-LA', 'lrc', 'lrc-IQ', 'lrc-IR', 'lt', 'lt-LT', 'lu', 'lu-CD', 'luo', 'luo-KE', 'luy', 'luy-KE', 'lv', 'lv-LV', 'mas', 'mas-KE', 'mas-TZ', 'mer', 'mer-KE', 'mfe', 'mfe-MU', 'mg', 'mg-MG', 'mgh', 'mgh-MZ', 'mgo', 'mgo-CM', 'mi', 'mi-NZ', 'mk', 'mk-MK', 'ml', 'ml-IN', 'mn', 'mn-MN', 'mni', 'mni-Beng', 'mni-Beng-IN', 'mni-Mtei', 'mni-Mtei-IN', 'moh', 'moh-CA', 'mr', 'mr-IN', 'ms', 'ms-Arab', 'ms-Arab-BN', 'ms-Arab-MY', 'ms-BN', 'ms-MY', 'ms-SG', 'mt', 'mt-MT', 'mua', 'mua-CM', 'my', 'my-MM', 'myv', 'myv-RU', 'mzn', 'mzn-IR', 'naq', 'naq-NA', 'nb', 'nb-NO', 'nb-SJ', 'nd', 'nd-ZW', 'nds', 'nds-DE', 'nds-NL', 'ne', 'ne-IN', 'ne-NP', 'nl', 'nl-AW', 'nl-BE', 'nl-BQ', 'nl-CW', 'nl-NL', 'nl-SR', 'nl-SX', 'nmg', 'nmg-CM', 'nn', 'nn-NO', 'nnh', 'nnh-CM', 'nqo', 'nqo-GN', 'nr', 'nr-ZA', 'nso', 'nso-ZA', 'nus', 'nus-SS', 'ny', 'ny-MW', 'nyn', 'nyn-UG', 'oc', 'oc-FR', 'om', 'om-ET', 'om-KE', 'or', 'or-IN', 'os', 'os-GE', 'os-RU', 'pa', 'pa-Arab', 'pa-Arab-PK', 'pa-Aran', 'pa-Aran-PK', 'pa-Guru', 'pa-Guru-IN', 'pl', 'pl-PL', 'ps', 'ps-AF', 'ps-PK', 'pt', 'pt-AO', 'pt-BR', 'pt-CH', 'pt-CV', 'pt-FR', 'pt-GQ', 'pt-GW', 'pt-LU', 'pt-MO', 'pt-MZ', 'pt-PT', 'pt-ST', 'pt-TL', 'qu', 'qu-BO', 'qu-EC', 'qu-PE', 'rm', 'rm-CH', 'rn', 'rn-BI', 'ro', 'ro-MD', 'ro-RO', 'rof', 'rof-TZ', 'ru', 'ru-BY', 'ru-KG', 'ru-KZ', 'ru-MD', 'ru-RU', 'ru-UA', 'rw', 'rw-RW', 'rwk', 'rwk-TZ', 'sa', 'sa-IN', 'sah', 'sah-RU', 'saq', 'saq-KE', 'sat', 'sat-Deva', 'sat-Deva-IN', 'sat-Olck', 'sat-Olck-IN', 'sbp', 'sbp-TZ', 'sc', 'sc-IT', 'scn', 'scn-IT', 'sd', 'sd-Deva', 'sd-PK', 'se', 'se-FI', 'se-NO', 'se-SE', 'seh', 'seh-MZ', 'ses', 'ses-ML', 'sg', 'sg-CF', 'shi', 'shi-Latn', 'shi-Latn-MA', 'shi-Tfng', 'shi-Tfng-MA', 'si', 'si-LK', 'sk', 'sk-SK', 'sl', 'sl-SI', 'smn', 'smn-FI', 'sn', 'sn-ZW', 'so', 'so-DJ', 'so-ET', 'so-KE', 'so-SO', 'sq', 'sq-AL', 'sq-MK', 'sq-XK', 'sr', 'sr-Cyrl', 'sr-Cyrl-BA', 'sr-Cyrl-ME', 'sr-Cyrl-RS', 'sr-Cyrl-XK', 'sr-Latn', 'sr-Latn-BA', 'sr-Latn-ME', 'sr-Latn-RS', 'sr-Latn-XK', 'ss', 'ss-SZ', 'ss-ZA', 'st', 'st-LS', 'st-ZA', 'sv', 'sv-AX', 'sv-FI', 'sv-SE', 'sw', 'sw-CD', 'sw-KE', 'sw-TZ', 'sw-UG', 'syr', 'syr-IQ', 'syr-SY', 'ta', 'ta-IN', 'ta-LK', 'ta-MY', 'ta-SG', 'te', 'te-IN', 'teo', 'teo-KE', 'teo-UG', 'tg', 'tg-TJ', 'th', 'th-TH', 'ti', 'ti-ER', 'ti-ET', 'tig', 'tig-ER', 'tk', 'tk-TM', 'tn', 'tn-BW', 'tn-ZA', 'to', 'to-TO', 'tr', 'tr-CY', 'tr-TR', 'trv', 'trv-TW', 'ts', 'ts-ZA', 'tt', 'tt-RU', 'twq', 'twq-NE', 'tzm', 'tzm-MA', 'ug', 'ug-CN', 'uk', 'uk-UA', 'ur', 'ur-Arab', 'ur-Arab-IN', 'ur-Arab-PK', 'ur-Aran', 'ur-Aran-IN', 'ur-Aran-PK', 'ur-IN', 'ur-PK', 'uz', 'uz-Arab', 'uz-Arab-AF', 'uz-Cyrl', 'uz-Cyrl-UZ', 'uz-Latn', 'uz-Latn-UZ', 'vai', 'vai-Latn', 'vai-Latn-LR', 'vai-Vaii', 'vai-Vaii-LR', 've', 've-ZA', 'vi', 'vi-VN', 'vun', 'vun-TZ', 'wa', 'wa-BE', 'wae', 'wae-CH', 'wal', 'wal-ET', 'wo', 'wo-SN', 'wuu', 'xh', 'xh-ZA', 'xog', 'xog-UG', 'yav', 'yav-CM', 'yi', 'yi-001', 'yo', 'yo-BJ', 'yo-NG', 'yue', 'yue-Hans', 'yue-Hans-CN', 'yue-Hant', 'yue-Hant-HK', 'zgh', 'zgh-MA', 'zh', 'zh-Hans', 'zh-Hans-CN', 'zh-Hans-HK', 'zh-Hans-MO', 'zh-Hans-SG', 'zh-Hant', 'zh-Hant-CN', 'zh-Hant-HK', 'zh-Hant-MO', 'zh-Hant-TW', 'zu', 'zu-ZA')]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [string]
    ${Culture},
    
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ObjectRaw', Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Object', Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [AllowNull()]
    [psobject]
    ${InputObject},
    
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
    [string[]]
    ${Pattern},
    
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'FileRaw', Mandatory, Position = 1, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'File', Mandatory, Position = 1, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [string[]]
    ${Path},
    
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'LiteralFileRaw', Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'LiteralFile', Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [Alias('PSPath', 'LP')]
    [string[]]
    ${LiteralPath},
    
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'LiteralFileRaw', Mandatory)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'FileRaw', Mandatory)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ObjectRaw', Mandatory)]
    [switch]
    ${Raw},
    
    [switch]
    ${SimpleMatch},
    
    [switch]
    ${CaseSensitive},
    
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'File')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Object')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'LiteralFile')]
    [switch]
    ${Quiet},
    
    [switch]
    ${List},
    
    [switch]
    ${NoEmphasis},
    
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string[]]
    ${Include},
    
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string[]]
    ${Exclude},
    
    [switch]
    ${NotMatch},
    
    [switch]
    ${AllMatches},
    
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [System.Text.Encoding]
    ${Encoding},
    
    [ValidateRange(0, 2147483647)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidateCount(1, 2)]
    [int[]]
    ${Context})
    
  begin {
    # Ignore parameters that are only supported in v7+
    if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 7) {
      ('Culture', 'Raw', 'NoEmphasis').ForEach( {
          if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($_)) {
            $null = $PSBoundParameters.Remove($_)
            Write-Warning "Ignoring parameter $_, because it is only supported in PowerShell 7.0 or above."
          }
        })
    }
    # Set up the steppable pipeline.
    try {
      $commandToWrap = { Out-String -Stream | Select-String @PSBoundParameters }
      $steppablePipeline = $commandToWrap.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
      $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    }
    catch {
      $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
    }
  }
    
  process {
    $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
  }
    
  end {
    $steppablePipeline.End()
  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes up a lot.  Other options.  In the case of get-service, both -name and -displayname take wildcards:

```
get-service *win*
get-service -displayname *win*
```

Or if wildcards aren't available, but you need to know the property name, which is usually the column heading, in this case displayname:

```
get-service | where displayname -match win
```

Sometimes something like this gets some results.  It depends on what the string version of the object becomes:

```
get-service | where { $_ -match 'win' }
```

Occasionally it is useful to convert everything to a string and search it.  I'm not above doing this.  "/i" is case insensitive.

```
get-service | findstr /i win
```